# Can't return props from getInitialProps when in custom error page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have implemented a custom error page for my Next.js application by creating a custom `_error.js` file in my Pages folder, as explained in the docs. The problem is that any prop I return from `getInitialProps` turns out to be undefined.

So I tried keeping my custom `_error.js` page and putting the sample code in the docs:

```
import React from 'react'

class Error extends React.Component {
  static getInitialProps({ res, err }) {
    const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : null
    return { statusCode }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.props.statusCode
          ? `An error ${this.props.statusCode} occurred on server`
          : 'An error occurred on client'}
      </p>
    )
  }
}

export default Error
```

Still no luck: `this.props.statusCode` logs as undefined.

The problem is I don't know where to look to debug the issue. In any other page in which I use `getInitialProps` it works just fine. What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Several people are reporting this bug but it doesn't seem that it is being corrected. Zeit is using a custom HOC to handle errors :

https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/error-handling-in-async-getinitialprops~99400c6c-0da8-4de5-aecd-2ecf122e8ad0?m=MTUzOTUyMTA1OTE0Mw==

It works fine with me.

Someone extended on this idea and published a [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-with-error).